# DFS undergoing stackoverflow while finding the bridge in the graph

Tags: java, graph-theory, depth-first-search

My DFS is undergoing stackoverflow while finding the bridge in the graph. In this question I am provided with the edges along with their id's in a graph having vertices (1 to n ). I need to find whether the edge associated with given id (q queries) is a bridge or not. Please help me understand what's wrong with my code:

```
import java.util.*;

class TestClass {

static int time=0;
static class pair{
    int v,id;
    pair(int v,int id){
        this.v=v;
        this.id=id;
    }
}

static class graph{
    static int v;
    static ArrayList<pair>[] adj;
     graph(int v){
         this.v=v;
         adj=new ArrayList[v+1];
         for(int i=1;i<=v;i++)
            adj[i]=new ArrayList<pair>();
     }

    static void addedge(int u,int v,int id){
        adj[u].add(new pair(v,id));
        adj[v].add(new pair(u,id));
    }
}
    static void dfs(graph g,int[] disc,int[] low,int[] parent,boolean[] visited,boolean[] bridge,int src){
        visited[src]=true;
        disc[src]=low[src]=++time;

        for(pair p:g.adj[src]){
            int i=p.v;
            int id=p.id;

            if(!visited[i]){
                //System.out.println(i);
                parent[i]=src;
                dfs(g,disc,low,parent,visited,bridge,i);
                low[src]=Math.min(low[src],low[i]);
                if(low[i]>disc[src]){
                    bridge[id]=true;
                }
            }
            else if(parent[src]!=i){
                low[src]=Math.min(low[src],disc[i]);
            }
        }
    }

public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=input.nextInt();
    int m=input.nextInt();
    int q=input.nextInt();
    graph g=new graph(n);
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        int u=input.nextInt();
        int v=input.nextInt();
        int id=input.nextInt();
        g.addedge(u,v,id);
    }

    int[] disc=new int[n+1];
    int[] parent=new int[n+1];
    int[] low=new int[n+1];
    boolean[] visited=new boolean[n+1];
    boolean[] bridge=new boolean[m+1];

    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        if(!visited[i]){
            parent[i]=-1;
            dfs(g,disc,low,parent,visited,bridge,i);
        }
    }

    while(q-->0){
        int i=input.nextInt();
        if(bridge[i])
           System.out.println("YES");
        else
           System.out.println("no");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please help me understand what's wrong with my code

There is too much code for me to read ... and reverse engineer your intent.

A `StackOverflowError` typically occurs when a recursive algorithm recurses too deeply and fills the stack.   For example:

```
// This is a recursive infinite loop.  It will throw SOE
public void callMe() {
    callMe();
}

// This is a finite loop but it may throw SOE if 'n' is too big 
// or if it is negative
public void countDown(int n) {
    if (n != 0) {
        countDown(n - 1);
    }
}
```

That's the general idea ...

---

To find the cause of the problem in your code:

1. Examine the stacktrace.  That will tell you which methods and which lines of code are involved in the deep recursion.
2. Examine the code, and see if you can spot an obvious error.
3. Run the code in your IDE's debugger.  Set a breakpoint at a key method (involved in the recursion) and use the debugger's function to display local variables to try to understand what is going on.  The `dfs` method would be a good place to set a breakpoint.
4. If 3 isn't enlightening, add some trace printing to the code to help you figure out what is happening.  For example, print the value of `src` at the start of each `dfs` call.